# to-less infinitive or noun

Tags: clauses, word-class

Is the word "wonder" a noun or to-less infinitive here? What kind of a clause is "why Simpson wasn't immediately arrested in that incident".

> The transcript makes one wonder why Simpson wasn't immediately arrested in that incident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a to-less infinitive. Here "one" is a noun (meaning any person) and not a number. The whole sentence means that after reading the transcript, people will want to know why Simpton wasn't arrested at once in that incident.